# Foreign chroot with QEMU user mode, binaries not found unless full path is specified

Tags: gitlab-ci, qemu, chroot

I am setting up a foreign chroot environment to build for architectures other than amd64 from a GitLab CI image. Steps were mostly taken from https://www.hellion.org.uk/blog/posts/foreign-chroots-with-schroot-and-qemu/, except that I am skipping the schroot/sbuild part.

```
- export CROSS_ARCH=armhf
- export CROSS_ROOT=/opt/chroot/$CROSS_ARCH
- export DISTRO=stretch
- export CROSS_MIRROR=http://deb.debian.org/debian/
- apt-get update
- apt-get -y install debootstrap qemu-user-static binfmt-support
- mkdir -p $CROSS_ROOT
- debootstrap --variant=buildd --include=fakeroot,build-essential --arch=$CROSS_ARCH --foreign $DISTRO $CROSS_ROOT $CROSS_MIRROR
- mkdir -p $CROSS_ROOT/usr/bin
- cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static $CROSS_ROOT/usr/bin/
- chroot $CROSS_ROOT ./debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

When I now try to run a command in the target environment like this:

```
chroot $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static uname -a
```

the command exits with an error (nonzero exit status), but no error message is printed. It works, however, if I specify the path:

```
chroot $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static /bin/uname -a
```

And it gives me the following output, which indicates I am running inside the armhf environment:

```
Linux runner--azerasq-project-40807358-concurrent-0 5.4.109+ #1 SMP Wed Jun 16 20:00:10 PDT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Oddly, the following works:

```
chroot $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static /bin/bash -c "uname -a"
```

i.e. full path to `bash`, but no path for the command after `-c`.

Suspecting that there could be something wrong with `$PATH`, I ran:

```
chroot $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static /bin/bash -c set
```

I get all of the GitLab-specific variables, as well as a bunch of others, including the following ones:

```
MACHTYPE=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

When I run

```
chroot $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static /usr/bin/env
```

some variables (such as `$MACHTYPE`) are missing but `$PATH` is the same. So `$PATH` seems to be set correctly, and a diff of the outputs (after sorting) does not indicate anything that looks related – the extra variables for `bash -c set` look mostly bash-specific.

Why won’t `qemu-arm-static` accept binaries without a full path if they are on `$PATH`? Where else should I look to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why won’t qemu-arm-static accept binaries without a full path if they
> are on $PATH?

Because qemu-user is not a shell, it doesn't have code that would search the PATH. [This](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=linux-user/main.c;h=e44bdb17b853b1ec24410de498e1bdb0774135ea;hb=621da7789083b80d6f1ff1c0fb499334007b4f51#l711) is the piece of qemu-user code that opens executable image when it's started as in the examples that you give, and as you can see [here](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=linux-user/main.c;h=e44bdb17b853b1ec24410de498e1bdb0774135ea;hb=621da7789083b80d6f1ff1c0fb499334007b4f51#l630) `exec_path` comes directly from the command line.

On the other hand you can install qemu-user as a binfmt-misc handler, in which case the shell will do the PATH search and the kernel will invoke qemu-user with an open file descriptor of the executable file in the `AT_EXECFD` entry in the aux vectors.

Comment: Installing `qemu-user` as a binfmt-misc handler would presumably allow arm and amd64 binaries to call each other. Any sort of script (including Makefiles) may end up running a mix of arm/amd64 binaries. That would be undesirable in a scenario where I am building for a foreign platform, with a toolchain expecting to run on the target platform as the compiler does not support cross-compilation. I’d either have to make massive changes to the Makefile, or explicitly run the build in a pure arm environment. Hence `chroot $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static /bin/bash -c $COMMAND` is the way to go.

Comment: There's an attempt to make binfmt-misc file system namespace-specific ( https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20191216091220.465626-2-laurent@vivier.eu/T/ ), but AFAICS it's not in the linux mainline yet.